# vb.net TreeView IComparer

Tags: vb.net, icomparer

Why oh why doesn't this work? I found it on MSDN butit throws an exception:`Unable to cast object of type 'OutlookTemplates.com.NodeSorter' to type 'System.Collections.IComparer'.`

```
Public Class NodeSorter
Implements IComparer(Of Windows.Forms.TreeNode)

Public Function Compare(ByVal x As Windows.Forms.TreeNode, ByVal y As Windows.Forms.TreeNode) _
    As Integer Implements IComparer(Of Windows.Forms.TreeNode).Compare
    Dim tx As Windows.Forms.TreeNode = CType(x, Windows.Forms.TreeNode)
    Dim ty As Windows.Forms.TreeNode = CType(y, Windows.Forms.TreeNode)

    If tx.Text.Length <> ty.Text.Length Then
        Return tx.Text.Length - ty.Text.Length
    End If
    Return String.Compare(tx.Text, ty.Text)

End Function
End Class

....

 tv.TreeViewNodeSorter = New NodeSorter()
 tv.Sort()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement the *non-generic* `IComparer` interface.
(because `TreeView` predates generics)